# about linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

Hi
I have a question that :

for example  I have a linked list that has 4 elements. `[1,4,2,7]` and their index will be `0,1,2,3.`
when I remove the third element which is `"2"` and it index is `2` ,the index of fourth element will be `2` ,I mean that the index of `"7"` will be `2`? my problem is because of the code bellow.

with doubly linked list we can write such a this code:

```
(p1--> next) = p3;(p3-->prev)=p1;delete p2;p1 = (p1.prev);
```

how can i write it for linked list?
thanks

Comment: Looks like C to me? Not java anyway.

Comment: @jgubby I think its pseudocode, unless the tricky --> operator is doing some tricky stuff.

Comment: For a singly linked list, you simply don't need to update the previous pointers, since there aren't any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in java you just have the following for a linked list.  You don't need to/can't delete a node.

```
p1.next = p3;
```

Note: you would only do this if it is homework.  In the real world, you should use the builtin, well understood and tested classes.

Comment: java.util.LinkedList does have a remove(int index) method so when you say that 'You don't need to/can't delete a node' i believe that is incorrect.